# zsh path/file name completion on -file= arguments

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Can I enable zsh to complete path/filenames in a shell argument such as

```sh
command -file=/
```

I do get path/filename completion when I do `file=/<TAB>` without a dash

This is possible at least on Debian with bash completion is it possible with zsh?

Comment: The reason that you're going to wonder why you see different results to answerers is that you haven't told people the true spelling of `command`.  Autocompletion of arguments can be variable by command.

Comment: What I want is file/path completion regardless of the command. I discovered this while running "ant -Declipse.home=/usr/local/eclipse" that won't complete. But others won't as well so I want it not only for ant but for every command or argument with a slash in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enable magicequalsubst

> setopt magicequalsubst

Comment: Not enough for this case. Does it work with example above for you?

Comment: yes, and it also works in `zsh -f` -> `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit; setopt magicequalsubst`. a completer for an command could possibly mess that up but since your example is `command`, who knows.

Comment: I type `zsh -f` initialize a new clean shell and pop `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit; setopt magicequalsubst` but command -file=/<TAB> won't complete.

Comment: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-ALWAYSLASTPROMPT

I find that if I `unsetopt alwayslastprompt` it does what I want after reading: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2005/msg00895.html but also breaks/disables menu completion.

Comment: I must have missed something.. Works now.